# Second moment version of the multiple-sum Rogers integration formula

Tags: reference-request, lattices, homogeneous-spaces, geometry-of-numbers

I know the following theorems due to Rogers. Let $X$ denote the space of $n$-dimensional unimodualar lattices in $\mathbb R^n$, equipped with the canonical Haar measure.

> **Theorem 1(Siegel-Rogers)**. Let $k < n$, and $\rho : (\mathbb{R}^n)^k \to \mathbb{R}$ be a compactly supported,
> bounded, and Borel measurable function. Then
> $$
> \int_{X}\sum_{\substack{v_1,\dots,v_k\in L\setminus\{0\}\\\mathsf{rank}(\langle v_1,\dots,v_k\rangle) = k}}\rho(v_1,\dots,v_k)d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\dots \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\rho(x_1,\dots,x_k)dx_1\dots dx_k.
> $$

and

> **Theorem 2(Rogers)** Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a compactly supported,
> bounded, and Borel measurable function. Then
> $$\int_X \left[\sum_{v\in \Lambda-0}f(v) \right]^2 d\mu= \left[\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(v)dv \right]^2+ \sum_{p,q\in \mathbb Z, (p,q)=1}\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(px)f(qx)dx$$

I wonder if there is a **"combined generalization"** of these two results: specifically a formula like $$\int_{X}\left[\sum_{\substack{v_1,\dots,v_k\in L\setminus\{0\}\\\mathsf{rank}(\langle v_1,\dots,v_k\rangle) = k}}\rho(v_1,\dots,v_k) \right ]^2 d\mu=\left [\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\dots \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\rho(x_1,\dots,x_k)dx_1\dots dx_k\right ]^2+\text{ some additional terms}$$

Where "some additional terms" generalizes the Theorem 2 (in particular when $k=1$ they should match!)

I think such a result might lie somewhere in Roger's papers but I couldn't find it explicitly. Any reference or suggestions will be appreciated!